# Powershell 5 Get-content command to select specific word from text file with select-string command I get entire line

Tags: powershell-5.0

Powershell 5 Get-content command to select specific word from text file with select-string command I get entire line.

e.g I am running below command and looking to select only specific word, but output gives entire line in which test1 word exists.

PS C:> Get-Content C:\temp\testfile.txt | Select-String test1

hostname is test1, buildhistory 3 hours

and I am looking for command which willl only write **test1** in output

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
Get-Content C:\temp\testfile.txt 
`| Select-String -Pattern '(test\d+)'`
| ForEach-Object -Process {$_.Matches[0].Value}

Answer (score 0):

$failures = Get-Content "C:\Users\Documents\abc.txt" | Select-String -Pattern 'Error' -Context 0, 1

this will get lines after word Error in file abc.txt